# In Excel, how do I sort column data while keeping sorted to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007, sorting

Here is an example of the data I'm looking at:

```
A A01
A A08
A A04
A A07
B B03
B B05
B B02
B B06
```

I understand I can simply select the rows for Data Set A by Column B and then sort alphabetically, but is there a way to sort both Data Set A and Data Set B by Column B, while keeping Data Set A and Data Set B separate?

Basically I want

```
A A01
A A04
A A07
A A08
B B02
B B03
B B05
B B06
```

and not wind up with

```
A A01
B B02
B B03
A A04
B B05
B B06
A A07
A A08
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by two columns using the following steps:

- Data (ribbon), Sort
- Select Sort by: "Column A"
- Click "Add Level"
- Select Then by: "Column B"
- Click OK

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the A column and click on **Sort**.
2. Excel will prompt you to *Expand selection*. Select "No".
3. Continue to sort.

Alternatively, you can insert a column between column A and B, then proceed to sort both columns individually.